# Mapping trees on an estate map, using a csv file

Tags: illustration, automation

I wish to create maps showing locations of trees on an estate.

I would use an existing map of the estate as my base layer.

I would create an excel database of the trees. (ie CSV file)

Each tree would consist of an image symbol ID stored in a library and an x,y co-ordinate on the estate map to place it.

eg Symbol_ID : FS2 (this would be the reference name of a symbol in a library)
XY_Co-ord : 700:350

My main idea is having got the base map, I would then work with the graphics program to create the symbols for the trees and this would be useable with all drawings.  Then I would create a csv file of the symbol name and the x,y co-ords of its position on the map and somehow merge the two.

It would be nice if I could create a key block for the symbols used, giving the ID Code and their full Names.

Which software would be suitable on a MAC OSX Mountain Lion, particular with regard to ease of use? This is a personal project, I do not have a huge budget.

Because the maps will be different scales.  It would be nice if the software had a scaling factor for the symbol, when selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch. A complex one.

I would try "faking" an html page using thoose coordinates to "position" the icons using "absolute: position" on a css file.

But thinking about trees, this could work with a few dozens. Hundreds maybe... there will be a point where the file would be too complex to render.

Probably use the software Joojaa recomended. Xo)

Comment: That is an interesting idea, for small sites.  Could use PHP, to overlay the tree symbols on a site image. I actually want to create a printable map, so I guess I would be better with graphics software for that.

Comment: On further research - going to give google mymaps a try.  Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Well you might want to use a GIS (Geographic Information System) application for this. GIS applications can read your csv directly into their database as just another layer of info. This would then stop being a normal graphic design question (go to [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)) at this point, although GIS is often exported to illustrator for post processing. Some applications to look into:

- [Arc GIS](https://www.arcgis.com/), commercial
- [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/), open source

Comment: I have no experience of GIS.  I will research your suggestions. Thanks